# chef inspec output consists of error due to regex

Tags: ruby, inspec

When executing the below chef inspec command getting error.

```rb
describe command ("cat sql.conf | grep 'log_filename'") do
  its('stdout') {should match (/^'sql-(\d)+.log'/)}
end
```

Expected pattern matching is `sql-20201212.log`. pls check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex `/^'sql-(\d)+.log'/` doesn't match this string `sql-20201212.log`. You can try it out on https://regexr.com/

There are a few problems with your regex:

- `'` is in your regex but not in your string
- `.` matches any character expect line breaks, perhaps you want to match only a dot(?), if so, then you'd need to e.g. escape it `\.`
- you probably don't need to have `\d` in a group (`()`)

So, this regex `^sql-\d+\.log$` would match `sql-20201212.log` string. I also added `$` to match the end of the string.